# Receive creative name for SPONSORED_VIDEO & SPONSORED_INMAILS from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Just trying to fetch the creativename for creativeTypes = SPONSORED_INMAILS AND SPONSORED_VIDEO out of the LinkedIn API but I'm only able to receive creative names of SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE type.

In the doc I can only read fetching data for SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE by using the projection variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives#sponsoredvideocreativevariables

Does anyone have an idea how to get the creativename (subject) for SPONSORED_INMAILS AND SPONSORED_VIDEO?

Answer (score 2):

I know It's a little bit late but with this endpoint, you can retrieve info on a video add

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adDirectSponsoredContents/{{videoAddReffrence Urn}}
```

You can find the video Add reference Urn under the endpoint

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{{add Id}}
```

under the key 'reference'